# Prevent Carousel scroll within scrollable Container (Sencha 2)?

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I've got a Container with a header, content (Carousel) and a footer. The Container itself is therefor scrollable (vertical) to be able to scroll down to the footer. The Carousel can be swiped horizontally to change active item. I want to lock it to do only two thing:

- If starting to move vertically, only scroll Container
- If starting to move horizontally, only scroll Carousel

If you now grab the Carousel you are able to scroll both ways at the same time. Example code:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyContainer', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',

    config: {
        scrollable: true,
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'container',
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'label',
                        html: 'abc'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                xtype: 'carousel',
                height: 200,
                scrollable: false,
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'label',
                        html: 'x'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'label',
                        html: 'y<br/>y<br/>y<br/>y<br/>y<br/>y<br/>y<br/>y'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                xtype: 'container',
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'label',
                        html: 'def'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }

});
```

Using Sencha Touch 2.

Answer (score 2):

You might need to block the over scrolling .This will help to prevent both vertical scrolling and carousel item change happening at the same time.Try this code inside your scrollable of container.

```
 scrollable: {
           directionLock: true,
            direction: 'vertical',
            momentumEasing:  {
             momentum: {
               acceleration: 30,
               friction: 0.5
             },
             bounce: {
                acceleration: 0.0001,
                springTension: 0.9999,
             },
             minVelocity: 3
          },
          outOfBoundRestrictFactor: 0   
        },
```

Answer (score 1):

**If starting to move horizontally, only scroll Carousel**

Just add this to the config of your container :

```
config: {
  scrollable: {
    direction: 'vertical',
    directionLock:true
  }
}
```

I still haven't figured out how to lock the carousel when you scroll vertically. I'll let you know if I find out.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.It is working fine for me.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyContainer', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',

    config: {
        scrollable: {
            direction: 'vertical'
        },
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'container',
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'label',
                        html: 'abc'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                xtype: 'carousel',
                height: 200,
                direction: 'horizontal',
                directionLock: true,
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'label',
                        html: 'x'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'label',
                        html: 'y<br/>y<br/>y<br/>y<br/>y<br/>y<br/>y<br/>y'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                xtype: 'container',
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'label',
                        html: 'def'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
});
```